# How to open new activity from EditText

Tags: android

i tried this bt not working why.what should i change in my code. its like opening new activity by user input. what activity he wants !!

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    public Editable location;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);
        location=input.getText();
    }


    public void buttonClicked(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.benter: if (location.equals("khilgaon")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, khilgaon.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else if (location.equals("shantinagar")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, shantinagar.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
                break;
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: What you tried so far ?

Comment: public void buttonClicked(View v) {

        switch(v.getId()){

            case R.id.bkhilgaon :
                Intent p = new Intent(MainActivity.this, khilgaon.class);
                startActivity(p);
                break;
            case R.id.bshantinagar :
                Intent q = new Intent(MainActivity.this, shantinagar.class);
                startActivity(q);
        }
    }

i can jump any secific activity with this bt i want to read from EditText with another activity for opening that.

Comment: What error are you getting? Post the entire stacktrace. Use the 'edit' button towards the bottom-left of your post to add more info.

Comment: I cant understand how to compare with the string i have got from edittext to open specific activity which i have. Tim will you provide me the link because i tried bt dont found that process.

Comment: You want user to enter a name of activity and when clicking on button it should open that activity, right??

Comment: yes, you got my point.

Comment: check my answer please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);

input.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener()
    {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
        {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                switch (keyCode)
                {
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER:
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:

                        switch(input.getText().ToString()) {

                            case "khilgaon" :
                               Intent p = new Intent(MainActivity.this, khilgaon.class);      
                               startActivity(p);
                               break;

                            case "shantinagar" :
                               Intent q = new Intent(MainActivity.this, shantinagar.class);
                               startActivity(q);
                               break;
                           default:
                               //msg: activity does not exist

                         }

                        return true;

                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: thanks Fabio Venturi Pastor . i implemented your previous method it worked.thanks a lot.:)

Answer (score 0):

you have to write

```
         location = input.getText();
```

into

```
                  public void buttonClicked(View v) 
                    {

                    }
```

this method

Comment: public void buttonClicked(View v) {

        EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);
        location=input.getText();

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.benter: if (location.equals("khilgaon")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, khilgaon.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else if (location.equals("shantinagar")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, shantinagar.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
                break;
        }
    }
    }

Comment: ok add one more thing into it  location = input.getText().toString();

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like this??

```
private EditText input;
private Button btnGo;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);
    btnGo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGo);

    btnGo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public String str;

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            str = input.getText().toString().trim();
            Log.e("String ", "str" + str);
            if (str.equals("SecondActivity")) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void buttonClicked(){
    location = input.getText();

    if(location.equalsIgnoreCase("khilgaon")){
        ///intent
    }else if (location.equalsIgnoreCase("shantinagar")){
        ///intent
    }
}
```